# Using Animation & Animator on prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I was trying to play a on-death animation on a prefab object that spawns frequently during the level. I tried to use an animator with a trigger that is triggered during the collision. It was working until I put the object in the prefab, then I get this error:

*The object of type Animator has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.*

Then I tried using an Animation component on my prefabs with this code:

```
private Animation animBubble;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bubble")
    {
        animBubble = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
        animBubble.Play();
        Destroy(col.gameObject, 2);           
    }
}
```

But I still can't play any animation before they are destroyed. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Animator component, instead of Animation.

You can also try to delete the object in the animation as well. Remove your initial destroy code And add an animation-event that deletes the object at the end of your animation.